# Can you use "resulted" when talking about the equation and not the variables in it?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Given this equation:

> Selling Price = Direct Cost / 1 - Desired Profit

I can say that *Direct Cost / 1 - Desired Profit* resulted in 5.26 dollars.

However, is it  grammatically correct to say that  the **Selling Price** resulted in  5.26 dollars?

If not, what's a more adecuate word? Yielded? Turned out to be?

Comment: You probably want to add some parentheses in there.  According to the order of operations, "Direct Cost / 1 - Desired Profit" is exactly equal to "Direct Cost - Desired Profit".  You probably meant "Direct Cost / (1 - Desired Profit)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, is it grammatically correct to say that the **Selling Price**
> resulted in 5.26 dollars?

It may be correct grammatically, but it is incorrect semantically. The verb *result* is used to link cause and effect, a process and the outcome of the process:

> **result**
> verb [ intrans. ]
> occur or follow as the consequence of something : *government unpopularity resulting from the state of the
> economy* | [as adj. ] ( **resulting**) *talk of a general election and
> the resulting political uncertainty*.
> • ( **result in**) have (a
> specified end or outcome) : *talks in July had resulted in stalemate.*
>
> New Oxford American Dictionary

In your case, *Selling Price* itself is the result of the calculation. A result cannot result in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Technically I think you COULD say that but it does sound confusing.

I would say that the Selling Price "came out to be" maybe but that's not very formal. "Came to" might work, or just "equaled".

Actually I think "yielded" might be a good option. But you might want to consult a math or finance person depending on the purpose of your query.

Comment: the piece is actually a short story, so it doesn't has to be formal I guess.

Answer (score 0):

**result**

> noun
>   1.
>   a consequence, effect, or outcome of something.

By definition, there is nothing wrong with saying `resulted` in this sentence. I would suggest something like

- The selling price is/was X
- The selling price is/was equivalent to X